# Как сделать таймер обратного отсчёта?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
message: "Для повторного получения СМС кода подождите 60 секунд"
```

при нажатии на кнопку повторного отправления смс на номер телефона, c сервера приходит такое сообщение.
со статичным временем. Возможно ли сделать время динамическим? и чтобы после окончания времени сообщение скрылось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот буквально вчера делал так. Время сократил до 6, чтобы не ждать долго, пока сообщение исчезнет.

```js
const timerVal = document.getElementById('send-again-timer');

function initTimer() {
   let seconds = parseInt(timerVal.textContent.match(/(\d+)/)[0]);
   const timer = setInterval(() => {
     if(seconds < 1) {
       timerVal.style.display = 'none';
       clearInterval(timer);
     }
     timerVal.textContent = `Для повторного получения СМС кода подождите ${seconds} секунд`;
     seconds -= 1;
   }, 1000);
}

initTimer();
```

```html
<div id="send-again-timer">Для повторного получения СМС кода подождите 6 секунд</div>
```